# how to sort wmic process according to the memory size

Tags: windows, process, cmd, wmic

How to sort the `wmic process get name, workingsetsize` result according to the memory size for example it gives

```
sdf.exe  123
dfg.exe  3456
fgh.exe  234
```

what I want is

```
dfg.exe  3456
fgh.exe  234
sdf.exe  123
```

Comment: You need to pad them with leading spaces and then sort on the column where the sizes start.

Answer (score 0):

This will give you html output sorted (and as a convenience, display it immediately in the browser):

`wmic process get name, workingsetsize /format:htable.xsl:"datatype=number":"sortby=WorkingSetSize" >table.html
 && table.html`

(should be entered as single line at cmd prompt)

**While I admit this is probably *not exactly what you want*** it shows wmic output format extensibility and does not depend on any other tool/utility. If you need pure text output, you could for example tweak one of the included stylesheets or write your own `xsl transform` to format/sort the data. More information here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc757287%28v=ws.10%29.aspx